# Can I use case_when (or anything else) to write with a non-static string?

Tags: r, grepl

I have a data frame in R. I have this working splendidly at the moment as a test of my initial regex. For reference, I have `dplyr` and `magrittr` installed, largely for other reasons, and I am following some project-wide conventions as far as whitespace and closing parentheses are concerned:

```
frame %<>% mutate(
   columnA = case_when(
       grepl("WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}", columnB) == TRUE ~'HOORAY'
   )
)
```

The thing is, I would like to replace 'HOORAY' with whatever `grepl` actually found. Right now, I am of course searching for strings containing WXYZ followed by any number of spaces (0 included) and then a single- or double-digit integer.

If, for example, `grepl` found the string "WXYZ 22", I want the corresponding entry in columnA to be written as "WXYZ 22". But then if it finds "WXYZ5" later, I want it to write "WXYZ5" in its own corresponding entry.

I want, in pseudocode `TRUE ~ <what grepl found>`.

Can I do this with `case_when`? If so, is there a better way?

Comment: if you must maintain the `case_when` structure, the easiest way is probably the following: `grepl("WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}", columnB) == TRUE ~ str_extract(columnB, "WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}") `. Though this is a little silly syntactically, it does work.

Comment: @geoff I would like to maintain the ```case_when``` for reasons largely not related to this specific question, but if you have a more elegant solution, please do offer it. Thanks for this, either way!

Comment: It's really not that bad, you're just doing the string match twice which is inefficient. Obviously it's possible your situation demands it but an alternative in this contrived case is to just use `str_extract` in a mutate and handle the failed cases after. But as the adage goes, if it works it ain't stupid.

Comment: Also `grepl("WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}", columnB) == TRUE` could just be `grepl("WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}", columnB)` since `TRUE` and `TRUE == TRUE` are identical.

Comment: @geoff Ah well, if you post as an answer, I'd be glad to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `case_when` structure is necessary, this solution using `stringr` works:

```
grepl("WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}", columnB) ~ str_extract(columnB, "WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}")
```

Depending on what the bigger problem setup looks like, you could also just do:

```
mutate(columnA = str_extract(columnB, "WXYZ *[1-9]{1,2}"))
```

Note that columnA would be `NA` for situations where it fails to match. Also note that while `grep` expects the pattern first and then the target string, `stringr` functions expect the opposite.